# Display only the terms in the filter set using Views

Tags: views

I have got a view where I am displaying a view in a block.  Basically, I want to display a list of nodes that have a few specific terms associated with it.  So, for example, I want to show all nodes that have one of the following terms (red, blue, green, white).  So, my block should display two fields with the following criteria:

Fields
Content: Title (Title)
Content: Tags (Tags)

Filter criteria
Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Has taxonomy term (or Black, Blue, ...)

Sort criteria
Content revision: Updated date (desc)

My problem is, the result is looking fine, where it is displaying a list of all the nodes that fit the filters.  However, I would only like to display the term in the result set and not all the terms that the node is associated with.  So, right now, this is the what the block looks like:

---

### |Title        |  Tags

|Node 3     |  red, horses, yellow, dogs
|Node 5     | black, white, green, cats, rain, purple

### |Node 6     | camel, case, blue

I would like the block to look like this:

---

### |Title        |  Tags

|Node 3     |  red
|Node 5     | white, green

### |Node 6     | blue

So, in essence, display only those terms that are part of the result set.  How can I accomplish this with Views?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have played around with the configurations in Views, like @Mohammed Shammem said, and I have gotten it to display only the colors I want.  It is however, still displaying in separate lines despite selecting Group by Title under the Format settings option.  So, now it looks like this:

```
Tags    Title
White   Node 1
Blue    Node 1
Black   Node 1
Red     Node 1
Green   Node 1
```

I am close enough, but would appreciate more help on getting the tags in one row.

The relevant screen shots:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your view along with the group by node title that you did.

Comment: I have posted the images.  Btw, from Kerala?

Comment: yes from kerala

Comment: by the way you have exlude the grouping field the grouping field would show as a heading then you would use css to align it the way you want

Comment: Nice, I am from Kollam.  I have posted the images before and after exclusion, still not seeing how we would you css to put them in the same rows.

Comment: Instead of using table use simple html list. this would make it easier for you to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following.

Instead of displaying all the tags in one line display it in different lines. That is in the multiple filed settings you would choose it to display it on different rows. The result would be something like this

node 3 | red
node 5 | white
node 5 | green

Without the filtered nodes.

Now you would group it with the title field so that it would be displayed together.

To do the grouping you would do the following.

Click on the settings link towards the right of `Format :`

[image]

This would bring up a screen as shown below. you would select the field you want to group from the dropdown **Grouping field Nr.1**

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how I would group them by title so it would only display the terms in the result set?

Comment: I will update the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I did exactly that and grouped by Title.  However, now it is displaying each term (even the terms not in the filter) in a separate row.  How can I just display the terms in the result set all in the same row.  So each node will have one row in the table with only the terms blue, green, red, white displayed.

Comment: what type of view have you created is it a content view or a taxonomy view?

Comment: It's a content view.  I'll try and play with it and see if I could get it configured.  Thanks so much for continuing to help with this issue.

Comment: you need to create a taxonomy view instead. and create a relationship to the node.

Comment: Actually I don't want a relationship with a particular node.  I want this block to appear in the front page of my site.  Basically, want to just display a list of the nodes that have particular terms.

Comment: To be more clear, my results are working just fine, but the select statement is what I need help on.  I don't want it to select and display all the terms of the matching nodes.  Instead, I just want it to display only those terms that match from the filter.  So, a node could have like 13 tagged terms, but only 3 of those terms might fit the filter.  So, I just want it to display those 3 terms.  Basically, my results are yielding correctly, but my display is what needs work on.

Comment: Please see my edited question above.  Do I need to set Aggregate on?